# Тире после "для тебя"

Tags: тире

"Для тебя всё время мира".

Нужно ли здесь тире: "Для тебя — всё время мира"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от автора. Это эллиптическое предложение, тире зависит от наличия паузы. Если автор хочет логически выделить вторую часть, он поставит тире, если выделит первую часть, тире не будет.

У Розенталя:

> 1. Тире ставится при наличии паузы в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с
>    отсутствующим сказуемым): Влево, в углу, у дверей, на табурете — ведро
>    воды для жаждущих (Пом.); За калиткой — третий плац, строевой,
>    необыкновенной величины (Купр.); Мужики — за топоры… (А. Т.); И это вы
>    — при дочери? (Фед.); А в двери — бушлаты, шинели, тулупы… (М.); За
>    ночным окном — туман (Бл.); Олимпийский огонь — на нашей земле!
>    (Газ.); В роли обиженных — маленькие дети; И затем — минутная тишина;
>    Арбузов и дынь — горы; Коров — две; В ответ -— полное молчание;
>    Впереди — А. Карпов.
>
> При отсутствии паузы тире в эллиптическом предложении не ставится: А в
> доме стук, ходьба… (Гр.); Вдруг передо мною рытвина глубокая (Л.);
> Скрип шагов вдоль улиц белых, огоньки вдали (Фет); У Хохла пожар! (М.
> Г.); Револьвер на стол! (К. Т.); Справа дверь в соседнюю комнату,
> слева выход на террасу (так оформляются ремарки в пьесах); В этом вся
> суть.

Answer (score 2):

Какая уж тут воля автора!  **Здесь контекст нужен,** без него не обойдешься, сколько ни читай правила.

Да, факультативное тире  в эллиптическом предложении (схема: дополнение + подлежащее), но автору-то нужно **решение конкретное, а не только общее**.

Так как контекста нет, то придется его додумать.

(1) **Паузы нет, нет и тире.**

*Ты мой мир, и потому*

*Для тебЯ всё время мира.*

(2)  **Пауза и тире заданы параллельной структурой предложения:**

*Для тебЯ – пришёл рассвЕт,*

*Для тебЯ – всё врЕмя мира.*

Comment: Контекст:

— Есть время поговорить?
— Для тебя всё время мира.

Comment: Да, тире желательно  поставить. Здесь чувствуется влияние неполного ответа и повтора предполагаемого местоимения «для тебя».  Полный ответ мог бы выглядеть так: «Для тебя время всегда найдется. Для тебЯ — все время мира».  Здесь делается логическое ударение на местоимении и обязательная пауза после такого ударения, обозначаемая тире.  Конечно, вы можете и не ставить тире – как у нас тут любят говорить, «ошибки не будет». Да только тогда фраза потеряет всю свою красоту и выразительность, а зачем тогда она вообще нужна.